# What loads the Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility module when you start a fresh PowerShell prompt?

Tags: powershell

What loads the `Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility` module when a new PowerShell prompt is opened?

## Context

I have a proxy function for `Add-Member` that is located in the first path in my `$env:PSModulePath` environment variable.

Because `Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility` is being loaded somehow immediately when a prompt is opened my proxy function doesn't get implicitly used.

I don't want to have to explicitly import my custom module to use this function or add my module name before each call like `MyModuleName\Add-Member`.

My hope is that if I can learn what loads `Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility` maybe I can have that load my module as well or stop it from implicitly loading `Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility`.

Comment: To OP: you'll need to import the module before you can use it by adding it to the system `$profile` or otherwise.  All `$Env:PSModulePath` says is where to *find* modules if the command doesn't exist in the session, not to import all of them.  I'm pretty sure `Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility` is a **core dll** that PowerShell depends on and somehow preventing it from loading will cause unpredictable results.

Comment: You don't want to explicitly import your module, but you want something else to do it? Sounds like you could add the import code to your `$Profile` to get it to run automatically every time a prompt is opened?